# При копировании, текст вставляется вместе с фоновым цветом

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы текст вставлялся без фонового цвета, т.е. не наследовал фоновый цвет.

```js
test.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var text = this
  // Выделение текста
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(text);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);

  //Пробовал так избавиться от фона. Не помогло
  window.getSelection().toString()

  // Копирование текста
  document.execCommand('copy');
})
```

```html
<div style="background: #FF9933" id="test">22222222</div>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас фоновый цвет задается в аттрибуте `style="background: #FF9933"`. Для очищения атрибута `style`:

```
document.getElementById("test").style="";
```

еще можно вот так сделать

```
document.getElementById("test").removeAttribute("style");
```